# How do I restrict a vertical scrollbar to a layout excluding the toolbar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollbar

I've set up a vertical scrollbar for a UI screen when device has a landscape orientation.  The scrollbar is on the very right side of the screen and runs from the top of the screen to the bottom including a traditional toolbar at the top of the screen.  I'd like the scrollbar to only run from the layout below the toolbar down to the bottom of the screen.  I set the sytle up on the LinearLayout below the toolbar code but it did not work as I intended.  Please advise.

partial themes.xml:

```
...
<style name="scrollbar_shape_style">
    <item name="android:scrollbars">vertical</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarThumbVertical">@drawable/scrollbar_vertical_thumb</item>
    <item name="android:scrollbarSize">@dimen/custom_scroll_width</item>
</style>
...
```

partial land\layout.xml:

```
...
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
tools:context=".CardViewActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"  >

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" >
</include>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
    style="@style/scrollbar_shape_style"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
    android:useDefaultMargins="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingRight="2dp"
    android:paddingEnd="2dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingStart="0dp"  >
...
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Just have your ScrollView wrap the inner LinearLayout, not the outer one.

Comment: Yes, that should do it.  Thank you...clearly I need to take a break as your answer is very obvious...especially when I took a step back to look at the big picture.

Comment: We all need a second pair of eyes sometimes...  Cheers